# Handle errors generated by Call Back functions in Custom Ribbon

Tags: excel, ribbon-control, ribbonx, vba

I have a custom ribbon in Excel. There are a bunch of controls that use call back functions to implement actions and update the settings in the ribbon.

At times, when I am debugging code the ribbon refreshes and each one of those call backs generates an error along the lines of 'cannot run while in break mode'. There are quite a few callbacks so it is pretty annoying and inconvenient.

I am looking for possible ways to handle those error alerts. Because they are being generated by the ribbon it appears that normal error handling does not apply.

It would be good if I could identify when I am in 'break' mode so I could turn ribbon refreshing off when doing that but I was unable to find a way to do that.

Any ideas or insight would be appreciated...

Comment: There is no way to do this -I use custom ribbons as well- when you're calling outside procedures that interact in a way that cannot be debbuged by Excel VBA compiler you'll get those warnings by default. Compiler cannot deactivate them -it happens as well while you are interacting with VBA writing code routines-.

Comment: That's not the answer I was hoping for but thanks for sharing your knowledge. 
I am still thinking if could test for 'break mode' then I could add a condition to the 'invalidate' call which should theoretically prevent the issue. 
I guess I will need to ignore it for now. Thanks again.